# Anylogic : Oil terminal simulation

Tags: anylogic

I have to create a model where I have  different ships that arrive in the oil terminal.

For example, ships arrive every 11 hours +- 7 with a 60% chance being size A, 25% being size B and 15% being size C.

I am a begginner on anylogic, so this might be a basic question. I have tried to use a source that generates a boat every 11+- 7 hours but then I don't know how to force the source to generates boats of differents sizes at that rate. I thought  about using parameters, but I couldn't figure how to do that and I am still wondering if that would work in the model since the ship size has to affect loading operation times.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use agents to do this:

1. Create an Agent Type called Ship
2. Create a variable in your ship called size
3. In the source, in the action "on at exit" you can do the following:

   agent.size=uniform()<0.6 ? sizeA : (uniform()<0.625 ? sizeB : sizeC) )

I know it's weird to see this 0.625, but it's the number that you get 0.25/(0.25+0.15)

This is equivalent to an "if statement", check more info here:
http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/43.html

Comment: Okay! That's great! I'll get to work with that, my only other question regarding this is how to i make the loading time varry according to the size variable?

Comment: you create another variable called loading time and you do exactly the same like this: agent.loadingTime=agent.size==sizeA ? 1 (agent.size==sizeB ? 2 : 3);

Comment: But how do I get that value from the variable into the delay time field of my delay block?

Comment: on the delay you just use the agent value agent.loadingTime